# How to measure Lipo or lifepo4 battery with esp32

Tags: arduino, esp32, adc

my battery is lifepo4 3.32v currently.  then i set

`adc1_config_width(ADC_WIDTH_11Bit);`

`adc1_config_channel_atten(ADC1_CHANNEL_0, ADC_ATTEN_DB_11);` //set reference voltage
So if i applied 3.9v then i will se 2047 in monitor.
Code for measyre adc value

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        sum += adc1_get_voltage(ADC1_CHANNEL_0);
        delayMicroseconds(1000);
    }
    // calculate the voltage
    voltage = sum / (float)500;
```

But when i apply lifepo4 (3.2v) to GPIO36, i always see 2047? where is the problem?

Comment: Is the ESP powered directly from that battery?

Comment: i powered by usb cable and use GPIO36 to measure battery. but later it's will power up directly by battery. for example the lifepo4 max voltage is 3.6 so the max scale at 11db is 3.6?
 i also ask at other forum, they recommeded me to always use voltage divider. [link](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/2957#issuecomment-508133696)

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html

> At 11dB attenuation the maximum voltage is limited by VDD_A, not the
>   full scale voltage.

Check VDD_A.

Comment: is VDD_A a voltage applied to esp32 board, since i  power up by usb cable or Vin, it's always 3.3v ?

Comment: @QuangMinhLê No VDD_A is one of the chips pins. But if your board is powered by a 3.3V voltage regulator this pin is most likely connected to those 3.3V. Hence you cannot measure more than 3.3Vs